# Divergent sequence of random variables with expected value zero

Tags: probability, convergence

I am trying to think of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $X_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ but $E(X_n)\rightarrow0$.

Can you please show me some examples?

Comment: What mode of convergence?

Comment: almost sure convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you settle for convergence in probability:

$X_n$ defined to be $-n^2$ with probability $1/n$ and $n^2/(n-1)$ otherwise has mean zero but explodes in probability.

**For a.s. convergence**, construct the random variables from a common uniform random variable $U$, say, by taking $X_n = -n^2$ if $U<1/n$, and$n^2/(n-1)$ otherwise.